# Enable DKIM header in sent emails Exim or CPanel

Tags: cpanel, exim, dkim

I have enabled DKIM in WHM/CPanel/exim. DNS has valid DKIM keys for "default" selector.
Everything seems ok.

I downloaded email from gmail and looked in header and it misses DKIM header.

```
/var/cpanel/domain_keys/private
```

has valid key for that domain.